# Not getting entire message from Pub/Sub while pulling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am publishing a message to pub/sub using the gcloud command from the cloud shell like so:

```
gcloud pubsub topics publish <<some_topic>> \
--message={"ride_id":"3bdc2294-86a5-4f45-bb28-885d3a4c2ada","point_idx":1185,"latitude":40.76384,"longitude":-73.89548,"timestamp":"2022-02-10T02:24:06.11629-05:00","meter_reading":27.502796,"meter_increment":0.02320911,"ride_status":"enroute","passenger_count":3}
```

Now when I pull the messages from the consumer process using a subscription to the topic I get a base64 encoded string for the pub/sub message(normal BAU). But after I decode the message to UTF-8 it comes out as, passenger_count:3

Which is only a truncated version of the entire message. Any explanation in this regard/behavior of Pub/Sub would be very helpful. As well as a possible fix/workaround for this problem.

I am consuming the message with a Cloud Function having Pub/Sub trigger. The code looks something like below:

```
import base64

def subscribe_topic(event, context):
   # some code
   message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
   print(message)
   # some more code
```

The subcribe_topic() function serves as the entrypoint to my CF. When I print the message it usually gets reflected in the CF logs where I am able to see the truncated message instead of the entire one.
More on CF with Pub/Sub triggers [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub)

Comment: Can you show your code, please?

Comment: Can you share your code on how you decode from Base64 to UTF-8?

Comment: Updated original question with code.

Comment: More Info: I tried another consumer, to pull the Pub/Sub messages from a Cloud Composer Airflow DAG using the Pub/Sub Airflow operators. This time I don't decode the message to UTF-8 in the code(for verification) and instead get the original base64 encoded string that was pulled from Pub/Sub, and decode it in an online decoder. It happens to decode to the same truncated string i.e. passenger_count:3 instead of the entire message that was published.

Comment: In examples here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/topics/publish and here https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher the message data string is in double quotes.

Comment: Could you please run the message before you run the function or what it’s supposed to be retrieving, the issue might be related to what your message is receiving instead of pub/sub.

Comment: @RajnilGuha, have you inspected the message that is sent to ensure the full message is delivered to Google Pub/Sub? If you add a PULL subscription on the topic, you can use the Google Cloud Console web GUI to do "pull" and see the messages. You can even acknowledge them from there.

The reason for my question is because command-line arguments and quotes can sometimes not operate as expected. It depends on the shell and operating system. So perhaps the message is not sent in its full form.